# Куда можно выводить данные в админку wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

То есть, есть форма, нужно введённые в неё данные  выводить где-то в админке wordpress. Куда и как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо [написать плагин](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), который будет содержать [административную панель](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Administration_Panels). В частности, ф-я [`add_menu_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) создаёт страницу в админском меню.

Answer (score 1):

Так или иначе Вам придётся работать с файлом functions.php, который лежит в корне Вашего шаблона (если не лежит, то придётся создать). В нём можно прописать настройки для административной панели WordPress, в том числе и вывести какие-то дополнительные данные.

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-wordpress-admin-area/).